# MYSQL ORDER BY strtotime(column) ASC possible?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, strtotime

I have a column with varchars like 2.7.2019 10:15-12:30. I now want to sort the output from those dates, but I need to format them into a timestamp. How can I do that in the `ORDER BY 'column'`.
This is my current try:

`mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM ".$kTable."  WHERE class='".$class."' ORDER BY '.strtotime(.''datehours''.).' DESC");`
I know the varchars contain a range of timestamps but for sorting purpose it can do the job. Ranges like 12.12.2018 10:00-12:15 would be 12.12.2018 22:15 and would have a higher or lower value as ranges like 10:10-12:15 (22:25)

Comment: If I read your data correctly, the column actually contains a _range_ of timestamps.  How do you want to interpret this range regarding sorting?  By the way, it is bad table design to store a range of time in a single record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `str_to_date()` to convert the first part of the range to a datetime:

```
select . . .  -- whatever you want to select here
from t
order by str_to_date(substring_index(datehour, '-', 1), '%d.%m.%Y %H:%i')
```

Or whatever the right format is for your column.

Comment: Your query is missing parentheses.  I thought of giving an answer along these lines, but it really isn't meaningful to order a range unless we know exactly what the logic being used is.  Congrats on 134K this year in any case.

Comment: ORDER BY tr_to_date(substring_index(datehours, '-', 1), '%d.%m.%Y %H:%i' ASC wont work for me...

Comment: @Chryfi . . . Please explain why.  That is the sample data in your question and it does what you seem to want.

Comment: The logic is that the table contains events, which are in timestamp ranges of course and I want to sort them from newest to the soonest...

Comment: @GordonLinoff Answer makes my outputs of the columns disappear... EDIT the old answer without paranthese...

Comment: @Chryfi . . . Your title specifically says **ASC**, which would be from oldest to newest.  If you want the newest first, then just use `DESC` in the `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Yes, but the main thing to solve was the strtotime in the ORDER BY :) and your answer did it. Thanks! :)